# Bahujan Samaj are Vaishya not Shudra

Tags: scripture, caste-system

Most Neo Buddhists says that Bahujan samaj are Shudra and have major proportion demography because they have to serve above three Bhramin Kshatriya and Vaishya varnas

If you see how Shudra are defined in BH 18:44

```
Serving through work is the natural duty for those with the qualities of Shudras.
```

But if you see many Dalit/Shudra caste they all are either manufacturer , traders or service providers in which they have expertise and they sell their skills in exchange of Money.
That clearly states that they are monetary self reliant not dependent on Upper caste.

Some of the caste for examples are Dalits but are entrepreneurs.

- Jatav (Charmkar) leather manufacturers
- Matang(Maharashtra) broom maker
- Bunkar weavers
- Dhobi Laundry
- Barber

That means Bahujan samaj comes in Vaesyha Varna.

Any thoughts ..?

Comment: Varna system simply can't be applied in modern civilization in my honest opinion.

Comment: I am trying to redefine and understand political use of word "Bahujan Samaj"..  not in implementing any new social system.  Dependents cannot be more in numbers then Independent for any good wealthy state as India was called Golden Bird.   Bahujan Samaj was Vaishya is my point ..

Answer (score 4):

Since we are all culturally and genetically mixed which can be seen by general observation and scientific DNA analysis.... there is no importance of culture or blood of community. Even in Mahabharata time this was the case. There was no culturally pure community marrying into each other only. Almost everyone was mixed culture.

Yudhishthir said this in
The Mahabharata, Book 3: Vana Parva: Tirtha-yatra Parva: [Section CLXXIX](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03179.htm) -

> **It is difficult to ascertain one's caste, because of promiscuous intercourse among the four orders.** This is my opinion. **Men belonging to all orders beget offspring upon women of all the orders.** And of men, speech, sexual intercourse, birth and death are common.

Now it only depends on what their work is. The people you are describing and claiming to be Vaishyas, are probably all Shudras if they do not live by the code of conduct given in scriptures for Vaishyas. You have to live by Vedic way of life - **follow rules and regulations** - to be considered Vaishya.

Otherwise they are all Shudra.

Comment: Please try to always give the proper Chapter name / Section name, the edition name/ publication name, etc., of the book from which you have sourced or either an online link for the quotes or verses you're quoting in your answers.

Comment: @Vivikta Good.... Here's your upvote. You forgot edition name, publication name, publication house name, author's name, translator's name etc.

Comment: *You forgot edition name, publication name, publication house name, author's name, translator's name etc* - those are required if you're quoting from a Hardcopy and cannot find it in the online resources to hyperlink.

Comment: @Vivikta Tanslator & Author's name for example has nothing to do with hardcopy or softcopy. It is not found on the link you have given.

Comment: Allow me to give you a lookup at the [INDEX OF MAHABHARATA AT SACREDTEXT](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/index.htm). And you'll realize you **might** be wrong with - *"It is not found on the link you have given."* Sometimes, a thorough search is required. & Author is always Veda Vyasa - FYI

Comment: That is not the link you had given earlier @Vivikta if everything can be found online then so can the chapter or book number. So you shouldn't have written anything by your logic.

Comment: *"That is not the link you had given earlier"* || That's why **Sometimes, a thorough search is required.**  - It's the same "family" of links. So, it doesn't take the concept of "rocket sciences" to click and search through the page and find relevant information about the given text. Dear Kaushik Ji.

Comment: @Vivikta So you shouldn't have written anything by your logic.... just given link! It's okay no problem. You don't have to give explanation if you don't want

Comment: Good answer. Yes without following Varna rules as per scripture, one can't be put in certain Varna. Profession alone doesn't qualify the criteria.

Comment: Thanks @TheLittleNaruto :) Any non-believer occupied in trading or the army is much worse than a shudra who believes in &lives by the Vedic way actually.... so they are probably chandalas.... But I guess in the 4 fold classification they will only be shudra